# Can I update data without updating the LastModifiedDate for a particular transaction?

Tags: apex, dml, update, system-fields, systemmodstamp

I am migrating over legacy fields within a Salesforce org, but not performing any actual data updates (just moving some fields around).

For this reason, I'd like to preserve the existing `LastModifiedBy` and `LastModifiedDate` information.  Is there a way to turn the update of this system field off?

I'm currently planning on using anonymous Apex, but I'm happy to switch if I can preserve these fields in a different way.  I'm also happy to continue updating `SystemModstamp`.

I feel like I read this capability somewhere in the documentation, but now it seems that may have been a dream.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

The fields can be editable when inserting records, you need to raise a case with SalesForce to request edit access on the `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate`, `LastModifiedBy` and `LastModifiedDate` fields. This will allow you to edit the fields to whatever values you want when inserting the records.

Using this you could potentially create a new record which clones the old record, including the `LastModifiedBy` and `LastModifiedDate` fields and change the fields you want, insert the record and then delete the old record.

Comment: I thought those fields were only writeable on create not update though?

Comment: Looks like you are correct according to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008n11IAA)

Comment: So it doesn't make sense to do that as part of a release cycle, then, huh?